# instance openstack unreachable gatewaye external network

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have setup an ‍openstack with this structure . (kolla-ansible ["wallaby"])

**My servers are on esxi.**

```
Controle node: 192.168.8.13
compute node: 192.168.8.5
neutron node: 192.168.8.6
storage node: 192.168.8.3
```

kolla-ansible config (**global.yml**)

```
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
kolla_install_type: "source"
openstack_release: "wallaby"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "192.168.8.18"
docker_registry: docker-repo.davidlab.ir:5000
docker_registry_insecure: "{{ 'yes' if docker_registry else 'no' }}"
docker_custom_config:
  registry-mirrors:
    - http://docker-repo.davidlab.ir:5000
network_interface: "ens160"
neutron_external_interface: "ens192"
neutron_plugin_agent: "openvswitch"
enable_chrony: "yes"
enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backend_nfs: "yes"
enable_neutron_provider_networks: "yes"
enable_neutron_segments: "yes"
enable_neutron_sfc: "yes"
enable_neutron_trunk: "yes"
nova_compute_virt_type: "qemu"
```

**The deploy ends successfully.**

I login to horizon dashboard.

This is my scenario:
I have two private network:

```
   - 10.10.10.0/24 > Gateway: 10.10.10.1
   - 20.10.10.0/24 > Gateway: 20.10.10.1
```

And public network:

```
   - 192.168.8.0/24 > Gateway: 192.168.8.1
```

**The topology is as follows:**
[image]

**Networks is:**
[image]

**Router interface:**
[image]

**Public network details**
[image]

So, I have not to ping gateway external [`public network`]. But ping is not a problem in internal networks.
Result ping from the instance: [image]

Result ping from the Router in `neutron` node:

[image]

**Router route table:**

[image]

**Netroun interfaces**

[image]

I have ping gateway `192.168.8.1` From all nodes.

[image]

Why i don't have ping gateway public network?

Comment: Appart from a few images which should actually  be text in code blocks, your question is rather well written for the layout. Regarding the content, it is unfortunately [off topic](/help/on-topic) on SO because not related to programming. You should head to https://serverfault.com which is probably the most appropriate stack exchange site for this subject.

Comment: You could use `traceroute` to check the traffic path, maybe it would get some helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found it to be vpshere polices on the network virtual switches.  see the following and set all to accept instead of the default reject:

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-891147DD-3E2E-45A1-9B50-7717C3443DD7.html

make sure you reboot the vms for the changes to take effect.